# How to delete commits from local repository in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, github

I have 3 commits staging in the local repo in eclipse that I want to update on github. The problem is that in the first one of these commits I have 2 files overcoming the size of 100 mb so they are not able to be updated.
How can I delete these 3 commits without deleting changes in progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure we don't break anything, I would recommend creating a backup of the directory containing your local Git repository.

Then

1. Commit your "changes in progress"
2. Go to the "History" view
3. Right click the commit before the 3 conmmits which you want to remove
4. Select "Rebase Interactive", the "Rebase Interactive" view will be shown
5. Select the 3 commits and choose "Skip" as Action
6. Press "Start" and cross your fingers that you don't have any conflicts

Maybe choose only one file in step 5 if you have conflicts. You can cancel the Rebase by clicking the button "Abort" and make another try.

Comment: Hi Kai, thanks for your response! A question please: among step 4. and 5. appears on display a window asking me to select one of the following choices:       1. commit 2. stash 3. reset. Which one I should select? Moreover in step .5 you mean the whole 3 commits or just the 2 files involved?

Comment: The dialog appears because you have to commit your changes first (step 1). In step 5 you select the 3 commits which you want to remove.

Comment: Hi Kai. Sorry but I have just commited the changes within the local repo...

Comment: Ok; it worked successfully. Thanks again Kai, have a good time!